# Date-time local sending time from frontend to backend chages automatically and it subtracts the time by 2 hours

Tags: html, node.js, angularjs, datetime, datetime-format

I am using the `DateTime-local` in the HTML field to obtain the datetime from the users. I am sending the same to the backend which I am using to create the XML file. When I send the date to backend it subtracts itself by 2 hours for some reason.

I am not making any changes to it. I am currently in `Central European Time (CET)`, I am guessing its changing automatically to `UTC time` because CET is 2 hours ahead of UTC. I am just curious to know whats happening here.

I am using the HTML, AngularJS and Nodejs for my project and following are my code samples:

`HTML`:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" ng-model="formdata.EventTime">
```

For example, if I selected: 08 October 2020 12:30 PM then after the selection the field would appear something like this: `08/10/2020 12:30`

In the AngularJS, just before making the `HTTP` POST request to my `NODE.js` I tried to `console.log` the time and it appeared something like this:

```
Thu Oct 08 2020 12:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

Now finally when I `console.log` in my `Node.js` then it appears something like this:
`2020-10-08T10:30:00.000Z`

I am just curious to know if this is some default functionality?
I could not find similar questions elsewhere so I am posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, @Terry for the response. Based on his answer I did the following, I used the `moment` to convert my time from UTC to local. My project required me to retain the format of the date and syntax of it.

1. Install the `moment` library in Node.js.
2. When I was selecting 08/10/2020 15:30 in the `datetime-local` I was getting following date in `Node.js`:
   `2020-10-08T13:30:00.000Z`
3. I tried converting it using:

`EventTime      =   moment.utc(EventTime).local().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS.sss');`

4. Finally I got following output:

   2020-10-08T15:30:00.000

I hope if someone else has the same doubt this might help.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple enough reason for the difference. The outputs of both are showing the same instant in time, however the AngularJS log is formatting the date in  RFC 2822 format which shows the local timezone, while Node.js is logging the time in UTC formatted as an ISO 8601 time.

If you do this in both AngularJS and Node.js:

```
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

You'll get the same output (e.g.)

```
2020-10-08T10:30:00.000Z
```

Likewise if you try

```
console.log(date.toString());
```

You should get a similar output but in RFC 2822 format (e.g.)

```
Thu Oct 08 2020 12:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and clarification. I tried using the `console.log(date.toISOString());` in `node.js` and its throwing me error `TypeError: input.eventtimeSpecific.toISOString is not a function`. Is there anyway I can prevent `Node.js` from converting my `datetime` so that I can preserve whatever the string user has selected.

Comment: I would suggest sending dates back and forth to the server as either unix timestamps,e.g. 1602157264 or ISO 8601 formatted strings in UTC. e.g. "2020-10-08T10:30:00.000Z". This way you avoid different behaviour depending on the client timezone.